# Dynamically define enum in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Given the following JSON document

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "Arbitrary"
        },
        {
            "name": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "Allowed"
        }
    ],
    "edges": [
        {
            "tail": "Arbitrary",
            "head": "Strings"
        },
        {
            "tail": "Strings",
            "head": "Allowed"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to express through JSON schema, that the values of `tail` and `head` in an `edge` can only take values defined by the `name` key on a `node`?

My intuition for describing `edges` would have been something like

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties":{
            "tail": {
                "enum": {
                    "$ref": "#/nodes/*/name"
                },
            },
            "head": {
                "enum": {
                    "$ref": "#/nodes/*/name"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But JSON Pointer apparently doesn't allow wildcards (`*`) in the ref path `#/nodes/*/name`.

Comment: See discussion here: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/331

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. [According to the last draft](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.20):

### 5.20. enum

The value of this keyword MUST be an array. This array SHOULD have at least one element. Elements in the array SHOULD be unique.

Elements in the array MAY be of any type, including null.

An instance validates successfully against this keyword if its value is equal to one of the elements in this keyword's array value.